# Употребление деепричастного оборота при составном именном сказуемом

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, сказуемые, деепричастный-оборот

*Ваш ребёнок в абсолютной безопасности, играя в игрушки.*

*Ваш ребёнок будет в абсолютной безопасности, играя в игрушки.*

Можно ли употреблять деепричастие при составном именном сказуемом? Деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие, но составное именное сказуемое в большинстве случаев обозначает не действие, а состояние или качество.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Деепричастный оборот всегда относится к **глаголу**, который не обязательно является сказуемым. Поэтому для сочетаемости с деепричастием или деепричастным оборотом составное именное сказуемое должно содержать глагол-связку *в явном виде*. Соответственно, первое предложение грамматически некорректно и требует добавления глагола:

> Ваш ребёнок *пребывает* в состоянии абсолютной безопасности, играя в
>   игрушки.

Второе предложение формально корректно, но для ясности причинно-следственных связей требует изменения порядка слов:

> Играя в игрушки, ваш ребёнок будет в абсолютной безопасности.

(ср. Играя в игрушки, ваш ребёнок станет более сообразительным.)

Comment: Не могли бы дать ссылку, где сказано, что деепричастный оборот всегда относится к сказуемому, содержащему глагол в явном виде. Нашёл на Википедии: "Реже примыкает к именному сказуемому, выраженному кратким прилагательным или существительным" (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Деепричастие).

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=sanSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U0eyZdOXO_XExGsZ9XC-HYaAeYEKg&w=1280
... **деепричастие всегда относится к личному глаголу**... _Самостоятельное употребление деепричастий следует считать **крайне редким**..._ Далее следуют два примера, причём один из Тургенева, который долго жил во Франции и известен своими галлицизмами по этой теме (в примере глагол есть, но расходится с деепричастием по производителю действия - обычно это считается ошибкой)
(С. И. Карцевский, Лингвистическое наследие, т. 2 с. 187)

Comment: Источник же, на который ссылается википедия - Розенталь. Там при этой фразе **нет** примеров с отсутствием глагола в именном сказуемом:
http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-308.shtml

Comment: Спасибо. Ещё вопрос: с чего вы взяли, что в предложении есть причинно-следственная связь? Деепричастия в обоих примерах обозначают просто ситуацию, в которой ребёнок будет в безопасности.

Comment: Поскольку в исходном предложении есть только глагол-связка, то глагольная часть характеризует состояние, а не действие. Соответственно, деепричастный оборот не может трактоваться как добавочное действие и обстоятельство напр. образа действия, но может быть обстоятельством причины состояния (играя в игрушки, ребёнок напр. не будет искать спички и не полезет в розетку). Других смысловых обоснований связи с глаголом нет, поэтому предложение остаётся грамматически верным только в такой трактовке, при всей надуманности причины.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш ребёнок **будет в абсолютной безопасности, играя** в эти игрушки.

Сказуемое в данном случае обозначает состояние субъекта, а деепричастие ― действие, которое он совершает, находясь в указанном состоянии.

Примеры:

...**я буду спокоен, зная,** что ты находишься под опекою опытных людей… [Л. А. Чарская. Княжна Джаваха (1903)]

Внимательно **слушая** с поджатыми губами, Дик **сделался задумчив**. [Давид Маркиш. Убить Марко Поло // «Октябрь», 2003]

Comment: Что скажете про первый вариант?

Comment: Первый вариант при отсутствии ГЛАГОЛЬНОЙ связки мне кажется некорректным.