# Возможность употребления деепричастного оборота в безглагольном предложении

Tags: деепричастный-оборот

Возможен ли деепричастный оборот в безглагольном предложении? Например: Короткий день, в полсвечи горя.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440536/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC

Comment: Вообще говоря, невозможен. Но если Вы увидите такое предложение, то знайте, что сказуемое опущено, но подразумевается по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

В отдельном повествовательном предложении это нарушит логику синтаксиса. Поэтому нельзя, если нет задачи исковеркать язык. Но в художественных текстах встречаются и вполне себе живут подобные примеры в авторских ремарках в диалогах. Источник на вскидку не вспомню, но в переводах Пинчона можно наткнуться на что-то в духе:

"— Здравствуй, — Фред, протягивая руку".

Answer (score 0):

Невозможен. Деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие, которое поясняет основное, выражаемое глаголом-сказуемым, а оно в безглагольном предложении, очевидно, отсутствует.